# Read only unread mails using EWS client

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, exchangewebservices

I am reading a mail using EWS.

Could you please let me know how to filter out only the unread mails from a inbox?

Answer (score 6):

Try this code to get the *unread* mails from *inbox*

```
SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
findResults = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,sf, new ItemView(20));
```